# Multiple page cannot be opened in queryselector.click in phantomjs when the link is opened in new window(target=_blank)

Tags: phantomjs

```
The second page cannot be read in phantomjs --my code is below

var webPage = require('webpage');

var page = webPage.create();

page.onLoadFinished = function(){

        

        var title = page.evaluate(function() 

        {

    return document.querySelector("#link1").innerText;

});

console.log(title);  



page.evaluate(function(args)

{   

 document.querySelector("#link1").click();  

        

    }); 

    

    page.onLoadFinished = function(){

    

    var title1 = page.evaluate(function() 

        {

    return document.querySelector("#div1").innerText;

});

  console.log(title1);

  phantom.exit();

    };

};



page.open('http://staging.eubookingsdata.com/scrape1.php', function(status) {  

 

});




Here the first page is "http://staging.eubookingsdata.com/scrape1.php"

I want to read the content of div in "http://staging.eubookingsdata.com/scrape2.php"


Every thing is working fine ,but when i add target="_blank" in scrape1.php "link" it stopped working.


scrape1.php

<html>

<body>

<a id="link1" name="link1" href="scrape2.php" target="_blank" >click</a>

</body>

</html>



scrape2.php


<html>

<body>



<div id="div1" name="div1">hello world</div>

</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
      page.onLoadFinished = function() //1st level
      
      {
        
        var title = page.evaluate(function() 
        {
          return document.querySelector("#link1").innerText;
        });
        console.log(title); //1st level 
  
  
      
    //var newPage = webPage.create();
    //var page1=page.pages[0];
     
    page.evaluate(function(args){ //1st level
    
        document.querySelector("#link1").click();   
        
         }); 
       

};
page.onPageCreated = function(newPage){
     newPage.onLoadFinished = function(status){ //2nd level
    console.log(status);
        var title1 = newPage.evaluate(function() 
         {
           return document.querySelector("#div1").innerText;
          });
        console.log(title1);//2nd level
        phantom.exit();
    };
    };
page.open('http://staging.eubookingsdata.com/scrape1.php', function(status) 

{
 console.log("page1");
 
});